# Query based on key name in datastore viewer

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

How to write a query based on key name in google appengne datastore viewer ?

I need to get the entity from NDB Model `Product` where its key name is `abcd`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the [GQL reference](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlreference), you express what you want as:

```
SELECT * FROM Product
WHERE __key__ = KEY('Product', 'abcd')
```